# Help with Z score on probability questions.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

**1) Suppose Mel makes burgers whose weights are normally distributed with a mean of 10 ounces and a standard deviation of 4 ounces. 
a) Find the probability that Mel will makes a burger that weight exactly 10 ounces.**

$${\Large\int} _{10}^{10} 10/4  = 0$$

**b) Find the probability that a randomly chosen burger will weigh between 9 and 14 ounces. ( $ \mu = 10 $ and $ \sigma = 4$ )**

$P( 9 \le x \le 14) = 0.7426 $

(This is the z scores i got from the table. I dont think i have the correct answer to z1)

z1 = (9-10)/4 = 0.25 = 0.0987

z2 = (14-10)/4 = 1 = 0.3413

**C) Suppose Flo decides to adjust Mel's scale in order to trick him into making smaller burger. She wants to make sure that at least 90% of all the burgers weight below 9 ounces. If the standard deviation will stay the same, what is the mean burger weight that Flo is shooting for?**

$P( 9 \ge  x) = 0.9 $

$P( 9 \ge  x) = 0.3159 $

(I got the z score to 0.9. Also, don't know if this is correct. )

$ \mu = x - \sigma * z $

$ \mu = 9 - 4 * 0.3159 $

$ \mu = 7.73 $

**d) Mel is considering offering a quarter pound burger (or 4 ounces ) instead. For legal purposes, 80% of the burgers would have to weight between 3.8 and 4.2 ounces or Mel could get in trouble. If he can make the mean 4 ounces, what value of sigma would make his burgers meet the legal requirements?**

(I dont even know how to start this one. My attemp is this. )

Margin of error 0.2 ounces ( 4.2 - 4.0 = 0.2)

M.E = (z/2) $\sigma$

z = 1.28

(0.2/1.28) = 0.15625

Comment: So what do you need help with?? Are we suppose to just look through your work and tell you what's wrong. Please be specific. This is a lot of questions too. For part B just use normal CDF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your notation is incredibly confusing.  There are some things you've written that don't make sense.

For (a), your answer is correct but the equation you wrote is nonsense.  The probability of observing a continuous random variable having a specific outcome is zero:  $\Pr[X = 10] = 0$ if $X \sim \operatorname{Normal}(\mu = 10, \sigma = 4)$.

For (b), you have apparently found through your table that $$\Pr[9 \le X \le 10] \approx 0.0987, \quad \Pr[10 \le X \le 14] \approx 0.3413.$$  But I do not know of any table of the standard normal distribution that displays probabilities in such a way.  In my experience, all such tables show $\Pr[Z \le z]$ or $\Pr[Z > z]$ for $z$-scores indexed in the rows and columns; that is to say, the table is *one-sided*.  My solution, then, would be to write $$\Pr[9 \le X \le 14] = \Pr[X \le 14] - \Pr[X \le 9]$$ if the table displays $\Pr[Z \le z]$, and then $$\Pr\left[\frac{X - \mu}{\sigma} \le \frac{14 - 10}{4}\right] = \Pr[Z \le 1] \approx 0.841345,$$ and similarly $$\Pr\left[\frac{X - \mu}{\sigma} \le \frac{9-10}{4}\right] = \Pr[Z \le -0.25] \approx 0.401294.$$  Then the desired answer is the difference $$\Pr[9 \le X \le 14] \approx 0.841345 - 0.401294 = 0.440051.$$

For (c), you cannot write $\Pr[9 \ge x] = 0.9$ and then in the next step write $\Pr[ 9 \ge x] = 0.3159$.  That makes no sense.  Instead, if we require $X_{\rm new} \sim \operatorname{Normal}(\mu_{\rm new}, \sigma = 4)$, that is to say, $X_{\rm new}$ to be a normal random variable with some new mean $\mu_{\rm new}$ and the same standard deviation $\sigma = 4$ as $X$, and we also require $$\Pr[X_{\rm new} \le 9] = 0.9,$$ then we can standardize:  $$\Pr\left[\frac{X_{\rm new} - \mu_{\rm new}}{\sigma} \le \frac{9 - \mu_{\rm new}}{4}\right] = \Pr\left[Z \le \frac{9 - \mu_{\rm new}}{4}\right] = 0.9.$$  Since we need to solve for $\mu_{\rm new}$, we need to find a $z$-score that corresponds to $\Pr[Z \le z] = 0.9$, or $z \approx 1.28155$.  Then we have $$\frac{9 - \mu_{\rm new}}{4} = 1.28155,$$ and solving this gives the result $$\mu_{\rm new} \approx 3.87379.$$

For (d) we apply the same principle as in (c) only to the standard deviation:  Let $X_{\rm qp} \sim \operatorname{Normal}(\mu = 4, \sigma_{\rm qp})$ represent the weight of a quarter-pounder burger.  Then we need to find $\sigma_{\rm qp}$ such that $$\Pr[3.8 \le X_{\rm qp} \le 4.2] = 0.8.$$  Standardize:  $$\Pr\left[\frac{3.8 - 4}{\sigma_{\rm qp}} \le \frac{X_{\rm qp} - \mu}{\sigma_{\rm qp}} \le \frac{4.2 - 4}{\sigma_{\rm qp}}\right] = 0.8.$$  But since $X_{\rm qp}$ and therefore $Z$ are symmetric distributions about their means, we can also reason that the above is equivalent to $$\Pr\left[Z \le \frac{0.2}{\sigma_{\rm qp}}\right] = 0.9.$$  (Think about this one for a bit.)  How would we solve for $\sigma_{\rm qp}$?

Comment: Nice informative answer +1

Comment: @heropup Thank you very much for clearing this up for me. I apologize for my bizarre notation.